# I need help using Dictionary of dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to collect items in a dictionary:

```
enter code here

key1:
[
 ('text1', ['a', 'b', 'c']), 
 ('text2', ['f', 'g']), 
 ('text3',['h','i'])
]
#I tried to use collections.defaultdict() as
mydict = collections.defaultdict(list) 
temp = collections.defaultdict(list)
temp["text1"].append(['a', 'b', 'c'])
temp["text2"].append(['f', 'g'])
temp["text3"].append(['h','i'])

mydict[key] = temp
```

I am confused and I am new to python. Above structure doesn't need to be a list I just wanted to hold these multiple things with key1, there would be multiple keys like key1.

Please advice me the best way I can do it, Also I want to sort this dictionary based on the top level keys (key1, key2 etc).

Comment: There are tutorials out there geared towards teaching you python. SO does not teach nor provide tutorials. Try this one: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ and follow it through to learn the basics of python language.  Your posted code is not a valid python dictionary syntax at all -  read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries to get some idea how to work with dicts.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: Thank you folks! I will keep these things in mind.

Comment: I have one question though, sometime tutorials things are not quite obvious as we try to learn the best way. I won't say I haven't looked into the tutorials. I would have appreciated more if apart from advice Patrick would have told me the right way here.

Answer (score -1):

```
temp = {}
mydict = {}
temp["text1"] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
temp["text2"] = ['f', 'g']
temp["text3"] = ['h','i']
mydict['key1'] = list(temp.items())
mydict
```

the output is:

```
{'key1': [('text1', ['a', 'b', 'c']),
  ('text2', ['f', 'g']),
  ('text3', ['h', 'i'])]}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)